# How fix progress bar in listView?

Tags: android, listview

I have listView and cursorAdapter, in real time i am getting data from a server and updating list view items using `notifyChange(uri, null);`. But also i use progress bar and when my data have changed it update progress bar too.

Can I update the data without reset progressBar?

[image]

Comment: can't you just hide the progress bar while updating the data? Show the progress bar till you are waiting for response and as soon as response comes hide it.

Comment: Have you tried to start progress bar after some delay? For example, after 200ms? I.e. if data comes from cache - there's no sense of showing indicator, as request would be done within dozens of milliseconds, etc.   Anyway, it'd be easier to suggest, if you add some code into the question

Comment: I will Recommend to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov i can't use delay, and i really don't know what code i can add, because it is really very easy

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal hm, how `RecyclerView` will help, if i will be use cursorAdapter for `RecyclerView` it will exactly like `ListView `